# Is this dummy algorithm really good?

Tags: algorithm

I was solving some easy task and found that my dummy decision theoretically takes constant time. Task is following - get a string of input string without stop-chars. So I've simply looped over stop-chars and deleted them. It is looped over the stop-chars so is my decision really only len(stop_chars)-dependent? And btw do you know how C-python perform **str**.replace() method?

```
inp = input()
stop_chars = ' ()-'
for i in stop_chars:
    inp = inp.replace(i, '')
print(inp)
```

Comment: This can't be constant time, because the length of the input is `n`, and you can't know where the stop characters are. You could end up looking through all `n` characters, meaning it's `O(n)`. It's linear, not constant.

Comment: The replace function will take linear time, you have a constant number of stop chars. So it probably won't be worse than O(n) either. But the algorithm is not optimal as each stop char is searched and  processed separately.

Comment: Typically, `replace` is also `O(n)` in the length of the string, except cases where the replacement length equals the input length.